# Squirrel for Windows - Setup/Install fails on Windows 7

Tags: c#, squirrel.windows

I am building a .net 4.5 (c#) app and packaging it with [Squirrel for Windows](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows).
As expected, the releasify command creates one Setup.exe file and one Setup.msi. The Setup.exe installs the app as expected on the two windows 10 computers I had access to.

On the windows 7 I used to build the app though, when I try to open Setup.exe, the window where I double clicked the icone goes in "please wait mode" (with the blue progress circle instead of the usual mouse pointer) forever. If I check the processes open at that point, I see three Setup.exe that I cannot kill with the kill process button or via `Taskkill` command. And all I can do at that point to kill them is pretty much rebooting.

As to the Setup.msi, it seems to do nothing I can see (tells me something like "checking requirements", and once it has, it just closes with no visible effect).

Any idea about what's going on or how I could find out?

Comment: Have you tried just running the .msi file directly?

Comment: Think so. But to make sure after reading your comment I rebooted, directly went to .msi, to no apparent effect (I checked C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local and couldnt' find my app).

Comment: Looking at [the docs](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows/blob/master/docs/using/install-process.md) running the MSI wouldn't work anyway. It's odd that it fails on the machine you built it on and works on others, it's usually the other way round!

Comment: Deactivating my antivirus solved the issue >< I wish Avast had told me "hey I'm blocking this" and saved me a few hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently years later this keeps hitting people so I'm posting the answer I had first put in the comments:

Deactivating my antivirus solved the issue >< I wish Avast had told me "hey I'm blocking this" and saved me a few hours